# G1 CG: long clean-up time

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, jvm

The G1 garbage collector is much better than the default one, but its clean-up time is unreasonably long, 27 minutes of clean-up after a 3-hour run:

```
SUCCESS
Elapsed time: 186m21.5s
all done, exiting...
[GC concurrent-mark-end, 1626.1982305 secs]
[GC remark, 12.3848395 secs]
[GC cleanup 14G->14G(16G), 1.6514012 secs]
```

The program is run on a 4-core processor with 16G of RAM, it uses only one thread (main). One core is always busy, presumably with the OS (Ubuntu Linux, trusty); when the program runs, the System Monitor shows less than 100% loading of the other 3 cores.

The program is started from a bash shell. No other software is run in parallel with the program.

***Is there a way to reduce the time spent after the program termination?***

Comment: I don't quite get it - why does the GC run after the program terminates? Is it some task that is scheduled in a continuously running JVM? If it is - why would the time taken for the *concurrent* mark-phase be of any concern to you?

Comment: @piet.t I have no idea why the program does not exit immediately, the behavior that I see looks meaningless, but this misfeature appeared when I switched to G1 GC. There is nothing in main() after the "exiting..." message, but I see these GC messages, and this is why i believe that GC continued to work after main() exited.

Answer (score 0):

It got better after I added the following code that terminates the process:

```
String command = "kill -9 "
                 + new File("/proc/self").getCanonicalFile().getName();
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```